# Analyze Isaiah 14:18-19.

Tags: history, isaiah, prophecy

What is the new thing God is doing in Isaiah 14:18-19? 
And what is the historical background of this idea?  Did it develop out of another Jewish concept?

Comment: Please add to your post the actual text to which you are referring from a widely used translation and/or the manuscript (I assume masoretic Hebrew) text. Please indicate to what particular idea you are referring.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange J. Hawk, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Answer (score 1):

Although critical scholars attribute Isaiah chapters 1-39 generally to Isaiah, son of Amoz, writing around the beginning of the late monarchy, the consensus is that the passages from Isaiah 13:1 to 14:23 were written much later, as they concern Babylon during the period of the Babylonian Exile.

The king of Babylon, who had hoped to live among the stars in his after life ([14:12-15](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Isaiah-Chapter-14/)) has been defeated. Exultantly, the author says that all the  kings of other nations lie in glory, but that the hated king of Babylon will have no such burial (14:18-20).

R. Mark Shipp(*[Of Dead Kings and Dirges: Myth and Meaning in Isaiah 14:4b-21](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=LTyDz6JUv28C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isaiah%2014&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihtL2KyZzQAhXJKpQKHXOvD_cQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=grave&f=false)*, page 137) describes the passage as a dirge and analyses its poetic structure.

Answer (score 0):

The bloody destruction of spiritual & literal babylon & God will be merciful to Jacob & overturn their captivity back,Israel will possess the gates of their enemies once more (genesis 24:60)NKJV what was meant for evil God will turn to good (psalms 21:11)NKJV the Lord will give them rest from all their enemies around.The Babylonian king will not be given an honourable burial deemed important for monarchs,the corpse of the Babylonian king will be thrown out like a rejected branch what a contrast to the branch of the stump of jesse which will bear abundant fruit (isaiah 11)